# Follow-up forms with Python Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to do a webapp with several forms succeeding one another with Python Flask. I want users on the main page to click the submit button and be redirected to another page (a captcha), then when clicking on another submit button on that second page be redirected again to a third page.

Actual result is they are redirected again to the home page instead of the third page when clicking the second page's submit button.

Here's what my Flask app looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, flash, redirect
# Other imports

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'Redacted'

@app.route('/') # Home page
def my_form():
    return render_template('security_circle_form.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST']) # Second page when clicking submit on first page
def captcha_post():
    # Some captcha code
    return render_template('captcha_form.html', image_url=imurl)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST']) # What I want to be the third page
def my_form_post():
    return render_template('list.html',#some args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5566)
```

How can I create a series of 3 following-up forms?

Comment: That would require forms, and redirects, neither of which you appear to have attempted to implement. The fact that you're chaining forms is no different to all the tutorials on how to verify forms from all the tutorials, the only difference being the routes that users get redirected to on a valid submission.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, the problem is I don't know how to know from Python when a user clicks the submit button on the second page. I don't know where to place my redirection code when that event happens in my script.

Comment: You write a form on the front end that sends the request you your server

Comment: you should have different `@app.route` for pages with different forms OR only one `@app.route('/')` and uses some data from form or cookies to recognize which form was used last time and then send different template.

Comment: @furas is there a pure Python/Html way of doing this, or do I have to use JS? I'm not sure how to send data to the server from the html form.

Comment: both mentioned methods use only HTML. Using different urls doesn't need JavaScript. Cookies you also use in Python - set cookie before you send data to browser, get cookie after getting data from browser. You would need JavaScript only if you want to replace form without reloading page - and then you would need AJAX.

Comment: frankly, in all situations you would need cookies to remeber if user correctly answer captcha and add access to last form. In cookies you may have to keep unique value which you would have to check in database. Without this someone would generate cookie to get access to last form (and skip captcha).